# Wrong Savon interpretation of my Ruby code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, json, savon

I've got a bad interpretation of my code or I don't understand how
let it works.

Basically I've got this request:

```html
def create_request
  return {} unless !@person.nil?

  req = {
    ProfileIDVersion: {
      ID: ENV['GBGROUP_PROFILE_ID'],
      Version: ENV['GBGROUP_PROFILE_VERSION']
    },
    CustomerReference: reference,
    InputData: {
      Personal: {
        PersonalDetails: {
          Title: @person.title,
          Forename: @person.first_name,
          MiddleName: @person.middle_name,
          Surname: @person.last_name,
          Gender: @person.gender,
          DOBDay: @person.dob.nil? ? '' : @person.dob.day,
          DOBMonth: @person.dob.nil? ? '' : @person.dob.month,
          DOBYear: @person.dob.nil? ? '' : @person.dob.year
        }
      },
      Addresses: []
    }
  }
  address_count = 0
  @person.addresses.each do |address|
    Rails.logger.debug 'Adding address'
    if address_count == 0
      Rails.logger.debug 'Adding current address'
      req[:InputData][:Addresses] << {
        CurrentAddress: {
          Country: address.country,
          ZipPostcode: address.postcode,
          AddressLine1: address.line1,
          AddressLine2: address.line2,
          AddressLine3: address.town_city,
          FirstYearOfResidence: address.from_year,
          LastYearOfResidence: address.to_year
        }
      }
    else
      Rails.logger.debug 'Adding previous address'
      req[:InputData][:Addresses] << {
        "PreviousAddress#{address_count}" => {
          Country: address.country,
          ZipPostcode: address.postcode,
          AddressLine1: address.line1,
          AddressLine2: address.line2,
          AddressLine3: address.town_city,
          FirstYearOfResidence: address.from_year,
          LastYearOfResidence: address.to_year
        }
      }
    end
    address_count += 1
  end
end
```

where I'm expecting to have in output:

```html
<ns:Addresses>
<ns:CurrentAddress>
<ns:Country>United Kingdom</ns:Country>
<ns:ZipPostcode>SP9 7EW</ns:ZipPostcode>
<ns:AddressLine1>3 Bayeux Mews</ns:AddressLine1>
<ns:AddressLine2>St Georges Road</ns:AddressLine2>
<ns:AddressLine3>Tidworth</ns:AddressLine3>
<ns:FirstYearOfResidence>2015</ns:FirstYearOfResidence>
<ns:LastYearOfResidence>2015</ns:LastYearOfResidence>
</ns:CurrentAddress>
<ns:PreviousAddress1>
<ns:Country>United Kingdom</ns:Country>
<ns:ZipPostcode>SP9 7EW</ns:ZipPostcode>
<ns:AddressLine1>3 Bayeux Mews</ns:AddressLine1>
<ns:AddressLine2>St Georges Road</ns:AddressLine2>
<ns:AddressLine3>Tidworth</ns:AddressLine3>
<ns:FirstYearOfResidence>2012</ns:FirstYearOfResidence>
<ns:LastYearOfResidence>2015</ns:LastYearOfResidence>
</ns:PreviousAddress1>
</ns:Addresses>
```

instead I've got that:

```html
<ns:Addresses>
<ns:CurrentAddress>
<ns:Country>United Kingdom</ns:Country>
<ns:ZipPostcode>SP9 7EW</ns:ZipPostcode>
<ns:AddressLine1>3 Bayeux Mews</ns:AddressLine1>
<ns:AddressLine2>St Georges Road</ns:AddressLine2>
<ns:AddressLine3>Tidworth</ns:AddressLine3>
<ns:FirstYearOfResidence>2015</ns:FirstYearOfResidence>
<ns:LastYearOfResidence>2015</ns:LastYearOfResidence>
</ns:CurrentAddress>
</ns:Addresses>
<ns:Addresses>
<ns:PreviousAddress1>
<ns:Country>United Kingdom</ns:Country>
<ns:ZipPostcode>SP9 7EW</ns:ZipPostcode>
<ns:AddressLine1>3 Bayeux Mews</ns:AddressLine1>
<ns:AddressLine2>St Georges Road</ns:AddressLine2>
<ns:AddressLine3>Tidworth</ns:AddressLine3>
<ns:FirstYearOfResidence>2012</ns:FirstYearOfResidence>
<ns:LastYearOfResidence>2015</ns:LastYearOfResidence>
</ns:PreviousAddress1>
</ns:Addresses>
```

As you can see I've got two Addresses block, one with current address and the other with
previous address, but need just one address block.

The guess the problem might be calling multiple time:

```
req[:InputData][:Addresses] <<
```

but I don't actually know how to solve it in order to have all the addresses in one block.

This is what I've got from my Spec test:

```html
    "Addresses": [
      {
        "CurrentAddress": {
          "Country": "United Kingdom",
          "ZipPostcode": "OX4 2QX",
          "AddressLine1": "36 Brasenose Driftway",
          "AddressLine2": "Oxford",
          "AddressLine3": null,
          "FirstYearOfResidence": 2002,
          "LastYearOfResidence": 2014
        }
      },
      {
        "PreviousAddress1": {
          "Country": "United Kingdom",
          "ZipPostcode": "AB1 1AA",
          "AddressLine1": "21 A Street",
          "AddressLine2": "Aberdeen",
          "AddressLine3": null,
          "FirstYearOfResidence": 1998,
          "LastYearOfResidence": 2002
        }
      }
    ]
```

Thanks to anyone will spend a minute to reply,
Caterpillar.

Comment: how did you add the run the code snippet

Comment: I've just clicked the { } symbol while I was writing the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bit of savon that does the conversion between a ruby hash and xml is a gem called gyoku. For gyoku, an array value results in multiple elements (whose name is given by the key). If you don't want that, then the value for the Addresses key must be a hash i.e your input should look like

```
{"Addresses" => {
    "CurrentAddress" => {
       "Country" => "United Kingdom",
       ...
    },
    "Previous" => {
       "Country" => "United Kingdom",
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Frederick! your answer was pertinent and is helping me to find out a way to create this class representation, but so far seems trickiest than expected... basically I have difficulties in creating a JSON rep without curly bracket between them... is you find a way let me know! ;)